# Problems with setInterval/clearInterval

Tags: javascript

I have some code which I am trying to use for a gallery, it takes URLs from an array then changes an image on the page. Starting the gallery works fine

```
var move = window.setInterval(function(){gallery_switch_script()},2000);
```

But when I try to clear it within a function it doesn't clear the interval but the rest of the function does work but it only works once

```
function bwd(){
clearInterval(move);
var move = setInterval(function(){gallery_switch_script()},2000);
var b = i-1;
var valueBwd = array[b];
$(".galleryImg").fadeOut(1500,function(){$(".galleryImg").attr("src",valueBwd);});
$(".galleryImg").fadeIn(1500);
```

}

This spits out no errors at all. This seems to be the only part of the code which doesn't want to work, apart from the fast-forward button which contains a clearInterval() also.

```
var array = new Array();
array[0] = "";
array[1] = "img/gallery_1.png";
array[2] = "img/gallery_2.png";
array[3] = "";
array[4] = "";
array[5] = "";
array[6] = "";
array[7] = "";
array[8] = "";
array[9] = "";
array[10] = "";
array[11] = "";
array[12] = "";
array[13] = "";
array[14] = "";
array[15] = "";
array[16] = "";
array[17] = "";
array[18] = "";
array[19] = "";

window.onload=function(){var move = window.setInterval(function()     {gallery_switch_script()},2000);};

var i = 0;

function gallery_switch_script(){

var value = array[i]
i+=1;
$(".galleryImg").fadeOut(1500,function(){$(".galleryImg").attr("src",value);});
$(".galleryImg").fadeIn(1500);

}

function fwd(){
window.clearInterval(move);
var move = setInterval(function(){gallery_switch_script()},10000);
gallery_switch_script();
}

function bwd();
clearInterval(move);
var move = setInterval(function(){gallery_switch_script()},2000);
var b = i-1;
var valueBwd = array[b];
$(".galleryImg").fadeOut(1500,function(){$(".galleryImg").attr("src",valueBwd);});
$(".galleryImg").fadeIn(1500);
}
```

This is all of my code.

Comment: You have a `;` where you should have a `{`

Comment: I realized that just as I added, it didn't change the clearInterval not working at all unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

because `move` is a local variable and not global.

```
window.onload=function(){var move = window.setInterval(function()     {gallery_switch_script()},2000);};
```

It is defined inside the window.onload "scope" and is not accessible outside of it.

So define move outside of the function and it will work

```
var move;
window.onload=function(){move = window.setInterval(function()     {gallery_switch_script()},2000);};
```

and

```
function bwd();
    clearInterval(move);
    move = setInterval(function(){gallery_switch_script()},2000);
    var b = i-1;
    var valueBwd = array[b];
    $(".galleryImg").fadeOut(1500,function(){$(".galleryImg").attr("src",valueBwd);});
    $(".galleryImg").fadeIn(1500);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me either, clearInterval(move) still doesn't work and doesn't spit any errors out.

Comment: BECAUSE you declared move again in the second function as a local.